# How to fix the sass selector issue in my case

Tags: html, css, sass

I am running scss lint for my project and it reports something that I am not sure how to fix.

My scss

```
#test-id {
    .table {
        .test {
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
}
```

Scss complains with

```
MergeableSelector: Merge rule `#test-id` with rule on line 7
```

I am not sure how to merge the selector in my case. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the rule on line 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what's on line 7, I would guess it's telling you to do this:

```
#test-id .table .test {
    color: #fff;
}
```

As there is no need for nesting in this case.

Comment: I guess there will be problem with ID selector too.